# How to "hide" VoIP traffic?

Tags: networking, skype, voip

I'm pretty soon gonna be punished by my telecom operator for using WhatsApp,Tango,Skype etc. From now on not only will I be charged for the 3G Connection that makes services like WhatsApp,Skype etc possible but also an additional charge will be imposed for the VoIP traffic.

My question is - Is there anyway I can fool my telecom operator ? or Is there some app that can help me in this situation ? When I using services like WhatsApp,Tango etc, I'd like to hide it from my operator so I don't have to pay any additional charges.

Comment: Maybe you can create VPN connection and talk through that? They are encodes traffic, but I don't know if your ISP can decode it. Err... and if you asking this, then probably, VPN could be also forbidden.

Comment: absuletely. While no one can say how your ISP classes traffic, by using a (decent) VPN they can't see the source or target port so they can't distinguish VoIP traffic from other interactive traffic - except by guessing based on packet size and frequency - which is difficult to for en-masse. You might find an OpenVPN tunnel configured to run over TCP will confuse them (strong encryption + TCP rather then UDP).  No guarantees though.

Comment: That's giving me some ideas. Now I need to find if there any apps on Android that can do help me with this. :) Might need to root my phone first though.

Comment: Why the downvote ?

Comment: Android phone has already embedded standard VPN client. You just need to find/setup a VPN server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use openvpn with free vpns ( www.vpngate.net/en ) or hidemyass vpnservice. The latter will be more reliable. I don't think your provider has any right to sanction you for using skype etc. Is that explicitly stated in you contract?

Edit:
You can instaroot it with towelroot, just remember to use something akin to supersu to prevent disarray. But why would you need to do this just to run a vpn client?

Comment: it was added in the fineprint quite recently.

Comment: Does this solve your problem? If yes, please mark the question as answered.

Comment: Any chance I can get this on Android ?

Comment: Get what? An openvpn client? Search for openvpn. As for hidemyass, I bet they made an app just for their service.